# Return the latest date from array of dates

Tags: javascript, date

I have json as follow:

```
  "reviews":[
    {
    "notes": "Great place, perfect location but the best part was the Staff. Thank you so much for making our trip so wonderful!",
    "date": "2015-04-18",
    "rating":{"overall": 100}
    },
    {
    "notes": "I messed up the days I was supposed to be there but they did everything they could to get me a room, which I did. The guy at the front was super nice and then drew me an entire map based off of how much time I had there in Rome. It was extremely helpful and the restaurant he recommends (a friends who you get 10% off of) had good lasagna. Great place for a really reasonable price. Also, the doors do not automatically lock for you room, so just remember to lock your door when you leave. ",
    "date": "2016-04-18",
    "rating":{"overall": 94}
    }
    ]
```

I am trying to get the latest date (most recent) so that I can print the associated "notes".

```
      function highestReview() {
        var maxNumb = [];
        for(var y = 0; y < data.reviews.length; y++){
          maxNumb.push(data.reviews[y].date);
        }
       var latestDate = new Date(Math.max.apply(null, maxNumb));
        console.log(latestDate);

      }
      highestReview();
```

I am getting "invalid date"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As per the [*docs*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#Description), *If at least one of arguments cannot be converted to a `number`, the result is `NaN`* And `new Date(NaN)` will be **`Invalid Date`**

Wrap the date string in `new Date` while pushing in array. When `DateObject` is passed through `Number`, numeric value representing `date` will be returned.

```js
var data = {
  "reviews": [{
    "notes": "Great place, perfect location but the best part was the Staff. Thank you so much for making our trip so wonderful!",
    "date": "2015-04-18",
    "rating": {
      "overall": 100
    }
  }, {
    "notes": "I messed up the days I was supposed to be there but they did everything they could to get me a room, which I did. The guy at the front was super nice and then drew me an entire map based off of how much time I had there in Rome. It was extremely helpful and the restaurant he recommends (a friends who you get 10% off of) had good lasagna. Great place for a really reasonable price. Also, the doors do not automatically lock for you room, so just remember to lock your door when you leave. ",
    "date": "2016-04-18",
    "rating": {
      "overall": 94
    }
  }]
};

function highestReview() {
  var maxNumb = [];
  for (var y = 0; y < data.reviews.length; y++) {
    maxNumb.push(new Date(data.reviews[y].date));
  }
  var latestDate = new Date(Math.max.apply(null, maxNumb));
  console.log(latestDate);
}
highestReview();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and compare the date as string, while it is an [ISO date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

```js
var data = { "reviews": [{ "notes": "Great place, perfect location but the best part was the Staff. Thank you so much for making our trip so wonderful!", "date": "2015-04-18", "rating": { "overall": 100 } }, { "notes": "I messed up the days I was supposed to be there but they did everything they could to get me a room, which I did. The guy at the front was super nice and then drew me an entire map based off of how much time I had there in Rome. It was extremely helpful and the restaurant he recommends (a friends who you get 10% off of) had good lasagna. Great place for a really reasonable price. Also, the doors do not automatically lock for you room, so just remember to lock your door when you leave. ", "date": "2016-04-18", "rating": { "overall": 94 } }] },
    latestDate = data.reviews.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        return !i || a.date > r ? a.date : r;
    }, undefined);
    
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(latestDate, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You must convert your date values to Date objects first:

```
function highestReview() {
        var maxNumb = [];
        for(var y = 0; y < data.reviews.length; y++){
          maxNumb.push(new Date(data.reviews[y].date));
        }
       var latestDate = new Date(Math.max.apply(null, maxNumb));
        console.log(latestDate);

      }
      highestReview();
```

Hope it helps