# Returning the latest date from an array

Tags: javascript

I have a fairly simple function that takes in array and loops through it.
The length of this array could any length.
Within the collection (item) is an entry called date1.

Tried applying this method, but got invalid date message:
[Return the latest date from array of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36838689/return-the-latest-date-from-array-of-dates)

```
    function transform(context, input) {
       if (!input){ return ""; }
       for (i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
           var item = artifacts.Artifact(input[i]);
       }
       return returnValue;
    }
```

What I would like to achieve is to identify the element in the array which has the latest date (including the time) and return fields from that element.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We would need to see your array to be able to help you.

Comment: please add your input array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020796/finding-the-max-value-of-an-attribute-in-an-array-of-objects

Comment: I'm not sure how to extract the contents of input array, its generated automatically be another system.  This code is run inside another application, kind of like an extension.  For simplicity lets say the array just has 2 values - id & date

Comment: You have to have access to the data to be able to work on it, you could just console.log it and paste what you find here.

Comment: I'm trying this approach, which produces an object but I can't seem to get the values out of it?
       latest = input.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r.date1 > a.date1 ? r : a;
    });
   

  return JSON.stringify(latest, 0, 8);